# display contact list using a list view with checkboxes

Tags: android

I am working on an android 2.2 app. When clicking a button I would like to display a list with checkboxes with all the contact persons from the list. After checking the persons from the list I want to display the phone numbers of the persons from the list. I don't know how to do that.

I don't know how to display in a listview with checkboxes all the contact persons from a list. Need some help.

This is my code for the ocntact list:

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
        {

          if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
          {        
              Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
              cursor.moveToNext();
              String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               String  name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              Toast.makeText(this, "Contect LIST  =  "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }//onActivityResult

}
```

How to put all the contact name and phone numbers in a listview with checkboxes and than when ok is pressed to save all the checked persons in a list or a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link must help you

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

UPDATE1: 
after:

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
```

write:

```
if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()){
   Log.i("LOG", "check box " + list.get(position).getName() + " is checked");
} else {
   Log.i("LOG", "check box " + list.get(position).getName() + " is not checked");
}
```

Comment: how to print in a log file the checked elements? I don;t know how to do it

Comment: something like this
if (item.checked) { Log.i("LOG", item.mName + " is Checked"); }

Comment: where do I have to put this? In what class? MyList class? Please post the code. In MyList class I've added a setcontentView(R.layout.button) where the layout button contains a listview called list and a button with id ok. How to print the cheched elements after pressing the ok button?

Comment: I would like to mention that I am refering to the example on 8. Tutorial: Domain Model and Rows interaction inside the link you gave

Comment: see UPDATE1, it's a sample, modify it to fit your requests

Comment: one mor question. where is the best way to insert / add/ put the elements checked? IN a new list? And If I want for example to than delete an element and add a new one and so one how should I this? Can I put in a list on a single position two arguments? For example a name and an e-mail address and than when I want , search a person just after the e-mail address?

Comment: yes, you can. just design a layout as list adapter, and then provide resource references in ViewHolder, assign them and use them. check tutorial again. the listview completely described there.

Comment: is not working. I've inserted you r code, but there is no Log information on the android phonw

Comment: click on your smartphone or emulator name on Devices view in eclipse

Comment: how to add the selected elements in a list ? i woudl also like to add the e-mail for each selected name. how to do tha?t

Comment: do everything that done for checkbox. define field in ViewHolder, define field in Model, assign new ViewHolder field in getView (inside if), set new ViewHolder field in getView (outside if). test it! this is solution, but you must try alone to achieve result.

Answer (score 0):

This Might Help You...

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Answer (score 0):

Well...i guess that the element from the list contains a checkbox and a text view.

You could add another text view to this element for the phone number and set it gone. Then checkbox should be set to listen for clicks, and when it is checked, set some text in the phone number text view and make it visible.

Hope this helps.